# How can I join two ktables with custom values (and custom serdes)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to join two ktables with custom values.
The documentation makes it clear for default types (with default serdes) - https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#ktable-ktable-join

```
KTable<String, Long> left = ...;
KTable<String, Double> right = ...;

// Java 8+ example, using lambda expressions
KTable<String, String> joined = left.leftJoin(right,
    (leftValue, rightValue) -> "left=" + leftValue + ", right=" + rightValue /* ValueJoiner */
  );
```

but when I use custom values I get a serialization error and there are no overloads for passing custom serdes. How can I accomplish this?

```
KTable<String, ModelA> left = ...;
KTable<String, ModelB> right = ...;

// Java 8+ example, using lambda expressions
KTable<String, ModelC> joined = left.leftJoin(right,
    (leftValue, rightValue) -> new ModelC("left=" + leftValue.Name + ", right=" + rightValue.Name /* ValueJoiner */
  );
```

Comment: Where the exception is thrown?
Could you add more information about exception?

Comment: Hi @BartoszWardziński the exception is thrown in the ValueJoiner and is this one: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to the actual value type (value type: com.test.kafka.producer.model.ModelA). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually understood what I was doing wrong.
The error message was a bit misleading:

> Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes
> via method parameters

But I did not want to change the default serde and ktables join had no overload to pass serdes.

The problem really was on the fact that I created the ktable by using the stream.toTable method which has no overload to pass serdes either. What I did was to declare the ktable before (with serdes) and then use the stream.to method.

Probably a newbie mistake, but here it is.

Comment: Would you mind adding the snippet for what the code looks like now. I think I am running into the same issue.